# Correlation and variance.

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation, variance

If the correlation between two variables is 0.50, then how much variance does X account for Y?
It seems very simple, but I can't actually get the point of the question, does it require us to calculate $\frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_y^2}$?

Comment: If you write `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`, the numerator and denominator will display full-size while staying inline.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Don't do that; writing $\sigma_X^2/\sigma_Y^2$ is preferable as it doesn't stretch line spacing so much.

Comment: @GrahamKemp True. In that case I’d go with `\left.\sigma_X^2\middle/\sigma_Y^2\right.` $\left.\sigma_X^2\middle/\sigma_Y^2\right.$ so that the fraction bar stretches all the way.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\\ \sigma^2_{Y} = \beta^2 \sigma^2_{X} + \sigma^2_{\epsilon} \\
$$

$$\beta = \frac{\sigma_{X,Y}}{\sigma^2_{X}} = \rho_{X,Y}\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X}}$$

$$\beta^2 =.5^2\frac{(\sigma_{Y})^2}{(\sigma_{X})^2}$$

$$
 \sigma^2_{Y} = .25 \times \sigma^2_{Y} + \sigma^2_{\epsilon} 
$$

Thus a correlation of $0.5$ means X accounts for  $25$% of the variance of Y

Comment: could you explain what is meaning of the denotation $\sigma_{X,Y}$?

Comment: It is the covariance.

Comment: Recall , @Qing , the correlation equals the covariance divided by the square root of the product of the variances. $~\rho_{\small X,Y} = \sigma_{\small X,Y} /\surd({\sigma_{\small X}^2\sigma_{\small Y}^2})$